# creating a column in R data table from another column based on a condition

Tags: r

I have a data table where I have list column "digits_list"  and count column "length_digits_list"
I want to create a "lower_value" column
if count is 3 take the first take the second value of value_list
else if take the first value

Here is the sample I tried. as you can see row 4 is wrong. digits_list can take value 1,2 and 3 only

```
df[, lower := ifelse(length_digits_list == 3, digits_list[[2]],
                                ifelse(length_digits_list == 2, digits_list[[1]],digits_list))]
```

but I'm getting wrong results
[image]

```
structure(list(digits_list = list(list("150", 
    "250"), list("250", "350"), list("350"), list("50", "150"), 
    list("0", "50"), list("250", "350")), length_digits_list = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), lower = c("150", "250", "350", "250", "150", 
"250"), upper = list("250", "350", Inf, "350", "250", "350")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your input df

Comment: can you share `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: I have added  the input df

Comment: @NAS_2339 Can you please describe your logic in greater detail?  Should `lower` be the leftmost of the last two digits in each list?  Should `upper` be the rightmost of those two digits, and default to `Inf` if that rightmost digit doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this interpretation of your logic: your `lower` and `upper` bounds are given by the last two digits in the list; if there is only one digit, it is used as the `lower`, and the `upper` defaults to `Inf`inity.

### Note

These solutions will work even when lists within `digit_list` are *longer* than three elements.  They will also work when lists are *empty*: `lower` will default to `-Inf` and `upper` will default to `Inf`.

## Solution 1: **`data.table`**

Here's a solution with `data.table`.

```r
# Load the necessary package.
library(data.table)


# ...
# Generate your dataset: 'df'
# ...


# Convert the listed text ("150") into numbers (150)...
df <- df[,
  digits_list := lapply(digits_list, as.numeric)
  
# ...and take the last two numbers from each list.
][,
  digits_list := lapply(digits_list, tail, n = 2)
][, `:=`(
  # Extract the leftmost (1st) digit as the lower bound...
  lower = vapply(digits_list, `[`, numeric(1), 1),
  
  # ...and the rightmost (2nd) as the upper.
  upper = vapply(digits_list, `[`, numeric(1), 2)
  
# Default to infinity for missing numbers.
)][, `:=`(
  lower = nafill(lower, fill = -Inf),
  upper = nafill(upper, fill =  Inf)
)]
```

Given a `df` like the one in your example...

```r
df <- structure(
  list(
    digits_list = list(
      list("150", "250"),
      list("250", "350"),
      list("350"       ),
      list("50",  "150"),
      list("0",    "50"),
      list("250", "350")
    )
    # length_digits_list = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
    # lower = c("150", "250", "350", "250", "150", "250"),
    # upper = list("250", "350", Inf, "350", "250", "350")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
)
```

this solution should yield the following `data.table` for `df`:

```r
   digits_list lower upper
1:     150,250   150   250
2:     250,350   250   350
3:         350   350   Inf
4:      50,150    50   150
5:        0,50     0    50
6:     250,350   250   350
```

## Solution 2: **`tidyverse`**

Here's a solution in the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org).

```r
# Load the necessary packages...
library(dplyr)  # ...for data manipulation...
library(purrr)  # ...and for iteration.


# ...
# Generate your list of digits: 'digits_list'
# ...


# Embed the list as a column ('dgt_lst') in a table (tibble).
tibble(
  dgt_lst = digits_list
) %>% mutate(
    # Convert each list into a vector of numbers...
    dgt_lst = map(dgt_lst, as.numeric),
    
    # ...and take only the last two numbers.
    dgt_lst = map(dgt_lst, tail, n = 2),
    
    # Extract the leftmost (1st) digit as the lower bound...
    lower = map_dbl(dgt_lst, pluck, 1, .default = -Inf),
    
    # ...and the rightmost (2nd) as the upper, defaulting to infinity.
    upper = map_dbl(dgt_lst, pluck, 2, .default = Inf)
  )
```

Given a `digits_list` like the one in your example...

```r
digits_list <- list(
  list("150", "250"),
  list("250", "350"),
  list("350"),
  list("50", "150"),
  list("0", "50"),
  list("250", "350")
)
```

this solution should yield the following `tibble` as output.  As you can see, the fourth row is correct, as are other rows that were wrong in your example:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  dgt_lst   lower upper
  <list>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 <dbl [2]>   150   250
2 <dbl [2]>   250   350
3 <dbl [1]>   350   Inf
4 <dbl [2]>    50   150
5 <dbl [2]>     0    50
6 <dbl [2]>   250   350
```